# UIPath Help in Data Entry

Tags: uipath

How do I program in UIpath 2 things

1. if there is event of error on data entry, user have to be informed.
2. how to reduce amount of human intervention?

I am new to UIPath btw. Thanks!

Comment: Just use a Try Catch and throw an error? Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Hi kwoxer, thanks for your reply. I was doing an assignment and was required to do something so that i can reduce amount of human intervention. But I tried searching but have absolute no idea how to program that. I will try the Catch and throw for my data entry. Thanks

Comment: Best start on UiPath is https://academy.uipath.com/ It's free and very good to come into the tool to get an idea of what is possible.

Comment: the academy.uipath doesnt really help much. In short, after basic uipath is done for google docs, i need to add an additional feature to 1. Reduce human intervention where possible and 2. if there is data entry error or items missing from the list, it expects the user to be informed of error. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

-For question 1: you can make use of the try catch activity in studio, where you can place in it a block of code that you doubtful about and that can cause errors, and in the catch part you can handle the error and instruct the robot on specific steps.

-For question 2: handling errors will decrease human intervention and is considered as best practice to eliminate human in the loop. but of course some scenarios may require human intervention, like validations or decision making steps.

Answer (score 0):

For Question 1 - As mentioned by others.
Use a Try / Catch / Finally

In the Catch add your exception handler.
You could then send the exception to an email, write to a log file or something like integrate with Raygun to send the exception there.

Question 2:
Use a 'Flowchart' XAML and utilise the 'Flow Decision' activities. Then you can assign decisions to each possibility. You could also use the Switch Case in the same style if you know the potential outputs.